# How does Scala's mutable Map update [map(key) = newValue] syntax work?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm working through Cay Horstmann's Scala for the Impatient book where I came across this way of updating a mutable map.

```
scala> val scores = scala.collection.mutable.Map("Alice" -> 10, "Bob" -> 3, "Cindy" -> 8)
scores: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(Bob -> 3, Alice -> 10, Cindy -> 8)

scala> scores("Alice") // retrieve the value of type Int
res2: Int = 10

scala> scores("Alice") = 5 // Update the Alice value to 5

scala> scores("Alice")
res4: Int = 5
```

It looks like `scores("Alice")` hits `apply` in `MapLike.scala`. But this only returns the value, not something that can be updated.

Out of curiosity I tried the same syntax on an immutable map and was presented with the following error,

```
scala> val immutableScores = Map("Alice" -> 10, "Bob" -> 3, "Cindy" -> 8)
immutableScores: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(Alice -> 10, Bob -> 3, Cindy -> 8)

scala> immutableScores("Alice") = 5
<console>:9: error: value update is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]
              immutableScores("Alice") = 5
          ^
```

Based on that, I'm assuming that `scores("Alice") = 5` is transformed into `scores update ("Alice", 5)` but I have no idea how it works, or how it is even possible.

How does it work?

Comment: I believe it is just syntactical sugar. There isn't some deep underlying lesson here as far as I understand.

Comment: As you can see, the `update` method is called, not the `apply` method.

Comment: immutable means **Read Only** and mutable means **Read/Write** so the issue was araised

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is an example of the `apply`, `update` syntax.

When you call `map("Something")` this calls `map.apply("Something")` which in turn calls `get`.

When you call `map("Something") = "SomethingElse"` this calls `map.update("Something", "SomethingElse")` which in turn calls `put`.

Take a look at [this](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/apply-update-methods.html) for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this: => to update list of Map

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.concurrent

val map: concurrent.Map[String, List[String]] = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, List[String]].asScala

def updateMap(key: String, map: concurrent.Map[String, List[String]], value: String): Unit = {
map.get(key) match {
case Some(list: List[String]) => {
val new_list = value :: list
map.put(key, new_list)
}
case None => map += (key -> List(value))
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you're trying to update immutable map. I had the same error message when my map was declared as

```
var m = new java.util.HashMap[String, Int]
```

But when i replaced the definition by

```
var m = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
```

the `m.update` worked.

Comment: hashMap is mutable collection