# what does += operation really do in scala map?

Tags: scala

As the code shows:

```
val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
println(map(1))
map(1) = 10
println(map(1))
map(1) += 10
println(map(1))
```

and the output:

```
0
10
20
```

However, in my opinion, "map(1) += 10" is invalid as in java, and even valid, the result after this line, map(1) should be 10.

So Why??? and what exactly operation "+=" do in map ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Scala's mutable Map update \[map(key) = newValue\] syntax work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604697/how-does-scalas-mutable-map-update-mapkey-newvalue-syntax-work)

Comment: I don't understand why you think that "the result after this line, map(1) should be 10"

Answer (score 6):

First, `+=` is an [assignment operator](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators), because it ends in `=` and isn't a comparison operator. This means that if there is no suitable method (and `Int` doesn't have a `+=` method), `map(1) += 10` is converted to `map(1) = map(1) + 10`. By the rules in [Assignments](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignments), *this* becomes `map.update(1, map(1) + 10)` and *this* becomes `map.update(1, map.apply(1) + 10)` because `map` is an object rather than a method.

Answer (score 3):

The question asked 'what exactly operation "+=" do in map ??' is not relevant to the situation you described. Map's method += adds entry (key -> value) to Map, so that map(key) == value.

So the question is: what does map(1) += 10 does.

This simple lines

```
  map(1) += 10
```

compiles into this javacode

```
  24: invokestatic  #36                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
  27: aload_2
  28: iconst_1
  29: invokestatic  #36                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
  32: invokeinterface #43,  2           // InterfaceMethod scala/collection/mutable/Map.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  37: invokestatic  #47                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
  40: bipush        10
  42: iadd
  43: invokestatic  #36                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
  46: invokeinterface #51,  3           // InterfaceMethod scala/collection/mutable/Map.update:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Remove boxing and unboxing ops - we are not interested in them(line 24, 29, 37, 43). Review the rest:

We get value that was in map

```
  27: aload_2
  28: iconst_1
  32: invokeinterface #43,  2           // InterfaceMethod scala/collection/mutable/Map.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Add 10 to it:

```
  40: bipush        10
  42: iadd
```

And accomplish update:

```
  46: invokeinterface #51,  3           // InterfaceMethod scala/collection/mutable/Map.update:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Seems map(1) += 10 is desugared to map.update(1, map.apply(1) + 10)

Answer (score 0):

In Scala Map. `+=` means

```
ms += (k -> v)  Adds mapping from key k to value v to map ms as a side effect and returns ms itself.

ms += (k -> v, l -> w)  Adds the given mappings to ms as a side effect and returns ms itself.
```

Comment: On mutable map it's syntatic sugar for `apply` + `update` or in this case `map.update(1, map.apply(1) + 10)`

Comment: But in this case it _isn't_ called on the map, but on `map(1)`.